# How do I open this door in Shroud Hearth Barrow?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I have found a door in Shroud Heath Barrow which looks almost exactly the same as the one in Black Falls Sanctum.

> *That* door was opened with Lucan's golden claw…

… but the symbols on this door aren't quite the same (wolf instead of bear), so I don't imagine I'm supposed to use the same one.

Where can I get the claw for this door?

[image: the "claw door" in Shroud Hearth Barrow]

Comment: I found an Emerald Dragonclaw somewhere along the line - I think it's safe to say there are a handful of these things.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Spoiler:

> Go back to the inn with the guy's diary and talk to the innkeeper.
>  He'll give you a sapphire claw as payment. You then use it identically
>  to the one you use in Bleak Falls.
>  
>  If you haven't started the quest, pretty sure you can just talk to the
>  innkeeper anyway and start it, then immediately fork over the diary to
>  get the claw.

Comment: I didn't see the journal until after starting the quest, but I can't be sure whether that's because I wasn't there or if I just missed it.  :-)

Comment: It's in the room with the ghost knight.

Comment: The trick is to take the journal rather than just read it. Taking it will advance the quest text.

Comment: @David Fullerton Thanks for the spoiler tag, I wasn't sure how to add it.

Answer (score 1):

Kill the elves spirit impostor, go back to the pub and the bartender will give you the sapphire claw.